# how to detect when a MKAnnotation is tapped

Tags: ios4, google-maps, mkmapview, mkannotation

i have a mapView, which shows many pins (MKAnnotation objects). i want to get the detail of each pin by tapping (clicking ) on it. please refer me to some tutorials or provide some sample code. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you implement the MKAnnotation protocol correctly, tapping should display the "title" and "subtitle" members automatically, i.e. without the need for any additional coding.

Take a look at this [MKMapView sample for Speedy](http://www.speedyapi.com/index.php/ios-samples) I just created, or simply download it [here](http://www.speedyapi.com/index.php/speedy-download/ios).

For further information about getting the click to your delegate take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092569/mkmapview-calling-didselectannotationview) post

Comment: **download and reference links are broken!**