# MKMapView calling didSelectAnnotationView

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I use `MKMapView`. On map I show clickable `AnnotationViews`. 
After click on `AnnotationView`, I push MyController to `NavigationController`. 
In MyController I click on the back button, after this my previous controller is show (do pop controller).
When I click on `AnnotationVIew` in my previousController callback **didSelectAnnotationView** does not rased. Why it happened?

Comment: [Swift version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34444999/1634890)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It because when I click on annotation it annotation selected and when I click on this annotation again it does not call callback `didSelectAnnotationView`, because this annotation already selected.

Comment: so how can i remove the the selection from annotation.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether you have added MKMapViewDelegate in .h file and seted the delegate in .m file

```
 mapView.delegate = self;
```

And still if it will not work check didSelectAnnotationView is properly written or not.

Comment: - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view{}    This is proper method. You can refer  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html

Comment: I have delegate MKMapViewDelegate and mapView.delegate=self is set. And didSelectAnnotationView is properly written.

Comment: Check whether method is overridden properly..and also check viewForAnnotation method is returning MKAnnotationView.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift:**

By Apple documentation (press Cmd + Click over the class name):

```
// Select or deselect a given annotation.  Asks the delegate for the corresponding annotation view if necessary.
public func selectAnnotation(annotation: MKAnnotation, animated: Bool)
public func deselectAnnotation(annotation: MKAnnotation?, animated: Bool)
public var selectedAnnotations: [MKAnnotation]
```

So **after performing all the actions** on the selected annotation call:

```
self.yourMapView.deselectAnnotation(yourAnnotation, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Oksana said: it's because the annotation view is selected and you should deselect it.

You can use : `[_mapView selectAnnotation:nil animated:NO];`

Answer (score 0):

Once we click on annotation it will call

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
```

on clicking outside of annotation it should trigger

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
```

but in my case i was overriding clicking outside annotation so i called method programmatically where ever needed:

```
[geoMapView deselectAnnotation:nil animated:NO];
```